# Operating BigDecimal give Unexpected Result

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

I'm currently using `BigDecimal` and here is one of my implementation for getting a number with 2 precision:

```
    mDbHelper.open();
    BigDecimal total = mDbHelper
            .getTotal(Type.Income, "20130101 12:00:00", "20131231 12:00:00");
    BigDecimal expense = mDbHelper.getTotal(Type.Expense, "20130101 12:00:00",
            "20131231 12:00:00");
    BigDecimal saving = mDbHelper.getSaving("feb");
    mDbHelper.close();
    BigDecimal remaining = total.subtract(expense.add(saving));

    Log.d("total get", total.toPlainString());
    Log.d("expense get", expense.toPlainString());
    Log.d("saving get", saving.toPlainString());
    Log.d("remaining get", remaining.toPlainString());

    try {
        percentRemain = (double) Math.round(remaining.multiply(new BigDecimal(10000.0))
                .divide(total, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue()) / 100;
        Log.d("percentRemain", "" + percentRemain);
        percentExpense = (double) Math.round(expense.multiply(new BigDecimal(10000.0))
                .divide(total, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue()) / 100;
        Log.d("percentExpense", "" + percentExpense);
        Log.d("before calculation saving =", saving.toPlainString());
        Log.d("before calculation total =", total.toPlainString());
        percentSaving = ((double) Math.round(saving.multiply(new BigDecimal(10000.0))
                .divide(total, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue())) / 100d;
        Log.d("percentSaving", "" + percentSaving);

        Log.d("multiply", "" + saving.multiply(new BigDecimal(10000.0)).doubleValue());

        Log.d("divide",
                ""
                        + saving.multiply(new BigDecimal(10000.0))
                                .divide(total, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue());

    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        percentRemain = 0.0f;
        percentExpense = 0.0f;
        percentSaving = 0.0f;
    }
```

I don't know why `percentSaving == 0.0` when `saving >= 10,000,000`

Any views? Please guide me.

Here is the variable value that I logged:

```
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/total get(29448): 41623000
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/expense get(29448): 7186545.0
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/saving get(29448): 10000000
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/remaining get(29448): 24436455.0
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/percentRemain(29448): 58.71
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/percentExpense(29448): 17.27
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/before calculation saving =(29448): 10000000
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/before calculation total =(29448): 41623000
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/percentSaving(29448): 0.0
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/multiply(29448): 1.0E11
02-28 16:55:12.250: D/divide(29448): 0.0
```

`percentExpense` has the same formula with `percentSaving`

Added my method and log. Sorry for the mess.

**Solution**

I have changed the formula to this and seems like it now returned the correct value.

```
percentExpense = (double) Math.round(expense.multiply(new BigDecimal(10000.0))
                .divide(total, 4, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).doubleValue()) / 100;
```

Comment: Well what's `total`? (I would suggest separating that combined operation into lots of little operations, so you can see the value at every stage.)

Comment: @JonSkeet please see my logged data. Thanks. okay will do that.

Comment: `24.03` is your `percentSaving` calculated using the values you gave and the code piece you've posted. I don't see `0.0` anywhere.

Comment: I'm getting the same result if the `saving == 9999999`, but when it is `10000000` the `percentSaving = 0.0`.

Comment: are you sure, you've given all the details you're supposed to give us? and nothing has been missed? If that's the case, it wouldn't give `0.0`.

Comment: on the Log i last updated, you can see the mistake lies on `divide`, but I don't see any problems with my formula.

Comment: `2403.0` - `divide` thingy's output.